# Can I conditionally compile clojure / clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there a way to in clojure / clojurescript to conditionally compile something depending on whether you're compiling to JVM bytecode of Javascript?

I am writing a small game in ClojureScript but want to keep the majority of the code platform neutral so I can convert to Clojure at some point. I also find that compiling in Clojure is better for finding errors in my code.

I have this working fine by having a directory of clj files that cljsbuild converts to cljs using crossovers.

Where I've come unstuck is trying to use core.async in my clj files. This is needed for cljs:

```
(ns gaz.system
    (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
    (:require 
        [cljs.core.async]))
```

While this is needed for clj to work

```
(ns gaz.system
    (:require
        [core.async ]))
```

I'd love to have one file with some form conditional require depending on how it's being compiled. Is that possible at all?
Con

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [cljx](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx). It let's you prefix s-expressions with e.g. `#+clj` or `#+cljs` to create different code for Clojure and Clojurescript.

Also, though I have not tried it so far, there is [lein-dalap](https://github.com/BirdseyeSoftware/lein-dalap) which seems to rely on pure, compilable Clojure to generate Clojurescript.